# KMS condition and quasi-free states

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In algebraic formulation of QFT, it is known that if a state is KMS with respect to some time parameter $\tau$, then the Wightman 2-point functions must satisfy certain conditions, namely stationarity $W(\tau,\tau') = W(\tau-\tau',0) \equiv W(\Delta \tau)$, complex anti-periodicity $W(\Delta t+i\beta) = W(-\Delta t)$, and some holomorphicity condition for $W(z)$ on the complex strip $\Im(z)\in (0,\beta)$.

I am fairly sure that the converse is not true, that even if a free field theory has Wightman 2-point function that satisfy these condition, the state needs not be KMS. However, I cannot find the place that says this (or the opposite claim). For example, if one restricts to a subclass of algebraic states $\omega$, can the converse be true? Would something like Gaussian states (is it quasi-free state?) suffice to make one-to-one correspondence between the KMS state and the three-properties of the Wightman functions?

For all practical purposes I just need to know this for flat space, but if the idea works for curved spacetimes in general (or at least spacetimes in which the relevant states are defined, that's good enough). I am also somewhat curious if Kerr black hole spacetimes would have something similar, since if I remember correctly there is no Hadamard states to begin with.

Comment: I think it is just a question of nomenclature. KMS is a condition for all possible pairs of operators ($A, B$) while for the Wightman functions are generally built from annihilation/creation operators (or simply scalar fields). But the point of the Wightman functions is that their knowledge is equivalent to knowing the state..

Comment: @lcv I don't think so, there can be states whose specification require that we know all the higher $n$-point functions, similar to how not every states in quantum mechanics are Gaussian

Comment: $A, B$ themselves could be made of many field operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double implication is in fact true for quasi free (aka Gaussian) states.

If I correctly remember you can find details in Appendix B of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.1034) paper of mine

*Rigorous construction and Hadamard property of the Unruh state in Schwarzschild spacetime
Advances in Theoretical and Mathematical Physics 15 (2), 355-447*

I wrote with C. Dappiaggi and N. Pinamonti several years ago.

For non quasi free states, the two point function does not contain the information of h point functions and therefore the non trivial implication fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think that indeed the double implication only holds for quasifree states. In my understanding, any operator in the algebra can be written as linear combinations and strong limits of Weyl operators, so one only has to check that
$\omega(\alpha_t(e^{i\phi(f)})e^{i\phi(g)})$ fulfills the KMS condition for all f and g, where $\alpha_t$ is an algebra isomorphism.  If $\alpha_t$ is an isomorphism, then
$\omega(\alpha_t(e^{i\phi(f)})e^{i\phi(g)})=\omega(e^{i\alpha_t\phi(f)}e^{i\phi(g)})$.

Finally, if the state is (even) quasifree, we get

$\omega(e^{i\alpha_t\phi(f)}e^{i\phi(g)})=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\omega(\alpha_t\phi(f)^2)-\frac{1}{2}\omega(\phi(g)^2)-\omega(\alpha_t\phi(f)\phi(g))}$.

The exponents can be written in terms of the Wightman function, which shows that if the Wightman function fulfills the conditions you stated then the KMS condition will hold.

For non-quasifree states, I would say stick to the fact that the cumulants of any distribution, even a classical one, are independent, but there may be subtleties beyond my scope.

Comment: Difficult to read. It would be better to use exp() instead of $e^{...}$.